# Linux route does not persist

Tags: linux, static-routes

I have a network where I have the host `A`, the host `B` (both Linux) and the gateway `C`. I am trying to reach the host `Z`.

The traffic, by default does:

`A -> C -> Z`

For some internal needs, I need the traffic to do:

`A -> B -> C -> Z`

In order to do so, I just add a route. So in `A` I execute something like:

`route add A gw B`

if I ping, I can see how the traffic does:

`A -> B -> C -> Z`

Which is good. However, as the time progresses, you can see how it comes back to (checked with `mtr`)

`A -> C -> Z`

and the routing table stills existing (`route -n`)

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

Comment: Does B become unavailable at any point in time?  Are getting an [ICMP redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Redirect_Message) from B?

Comment: Did you try setting B as default route with _route add A default gw B_ ? I think it may have something in common of mac addresses in common network segment. Moreover it may have something in common with ICMP redirects (is B a windows machine ? ?:) )

Comment: It sounds like `B` is sending inappropriate ICMP redirects.

Comment: Mac address are different, but I will check the ICMP redirects.

Comment: Following (this post)[http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/how-to-disable-icmp-redirects-in-linux.html] I disabled to accept ICMP redirects and same results. This is virtualized host based using Xen. Might it have anything to do ?

Comment: Can you post the /etc/network/interfaces file (or where the interfaces are defined in your distro) as well as ifconfig for the relevant interfaces on A and B?  What is router C?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you have
[image: Current]

And this is what you want
[image: Desired]

On A, you need to set B as your default gateway; via /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eht0 or /etc/sysconfig/network

This way, on reboot, the settings don't get lost.

On C, you should configure a static route for A to go through B.  Not always necessary, but consistent if you want B to route all A's traffic to Z and vice versa.

**Note** if you build static routes on the boxes, you may need to write scripts to load on boot-up to re-add the routes.  If you added the default gateway via terminal instead of the network-scripts, then this would be a good place to put the commands, so the default gateway gets readded on boot-up.